# How to retrieve data from JComboBox and store it in JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextfield

I have a JComboBox. I want to retrieve the data from it. I know I use the getSelectedItem() method. But then once I get it, I want it to convert it to a String somehow..or ultimately, display it on a JTextField.

```
 String[] fluids = { "      ", "string 1", "String 2"}; 
 fluidsList = new JComboBox(fluids);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming jTextField1 is your JTextField and fluidsList is your JComboBox, you'll have to have something like this

```
jTextField1.setText(fluidsList.getSelectedItem() == null ? "" : fluidsList.getSelectedItem().toString() );
```